# Godot inventory array, how to fill the first element

Tags: arrays, godot, inventory

I am making an array inventory in Godot. I have six `null` elements. I first use `int find(variant,int from 0)` to find the first null index. And then I use `insert(position,variant)` to fill in that null index. But I found that it keeps finding the `null` next to it and ends up filling them all. So, the result is a completely filled array. How do I make it fill the first found only once? Such as after I pick one item, one slot gets fill at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just realized I was also using

```py
for i in my_array.size():
    sorting func()
```

So, it loops the whole array and finds null and fills the whole array. I was thinking why [theraot's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71245769/14267427) didn't work. Now figured out:)

Answer (score 1):

The [`insert`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_array.html#class-array-method-insert) method, *inserts* the element. So the `Array` will have all the elements it had, plus the one you inserted (The `Array` will have one more element). *This is why the documentation mentions that it becomes slow on larger arrays.*

As a result, `insert` never gets rid of any `null` (or any other element) the `Array` had. Which is why you keep finding the same.

What you want is not to insert a new element, but to overwrite an existing one. You do that with index access:

```
my_array[index] = new_value
```

For example, it can be something like this:

```
var index_of_null := my_array.find(null)
if index_of_null == -1:
    # null was not found
    print("the array is full") #or whatever
else:
    my_array[index_of_null] = new_value
```

Here we search for `null` in `my_array`, and if we find it (if [`find`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_array.html#class-array-method-find) didn't return `-1`), we replace that `null` with a `new_value`. You should be able to adapt that code to your needs.